# How to resize header logo at magento?

Tags: magento-1.7

i m using...
getLogoSrc()->resize(100) ?>" alt="getLogoAlt() ?>" />[image]

Answer (score 0):

Either upload the image in the dimensions you want or put CSS/IMG tag constraints on it.